# Kendo UI Number Formatting Invalid template

Tags: kendo-ui, number-formatting

I'm using kendo ui and I tried setting a tooltip template like this:

```
tooltip.template = "#= series.name #: #= kendo.toString(value, 'n') # "
```

But the numbers like 527266 are showing like this : 527.266,00

How can I make it 527.266 ?

I tried as test:

```
tooltip.template = "#= series.name #: #= kendo.toString(value, '##,#') # "
```

which is an example in the documentation, and should give 527,266 according to the example but it's caughting an error of Invalid Template.

How can I make numbers 527266 look 527.266

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(kendo.toString(527266 , 'n0')` to hide decimal numbers. Since it is culture specific, you will need to include culture specific JavaScript file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Input: 527266</p>
  <p>Output: <span id="result"></span></p>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2013.2.716/js/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js"></script>
<script>
  kendo.culture("de-DE");
  $("#result").text(kendo.toString(527266 , 'n0')); // outputs "527.266"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find another way to kendo format as I'm pleased. the only workaround I'm using till now is:

```
template: "#= formatAmount(FundCurrency ,FundValue) #"
```

and in your Js create a function.

```
function formatAmount(currency, amount) {
    if (amount) return currency + " " + kendo.toString(amount, "#,##0.00");
    return "";
}
```

All this trouble just because # inside the format is conflicting with the special tags #= ... #, and unless you start to format the string using "\#,\#\#0.00" it won't work, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you, although I wanted to show up to 6 decimals but not complete with 0, aka: "123,123456" should look like "123,123456" but "123,12" like "123,12", with no trailing 0s.

If you want no decimal places, then you could use:

```
template: "#= kendo.format("{0:n0}", value) #
```

Or change the 0 part of n0 to add fixed decimal places. For example for 3 decimal places it will look like this:

```
template: "#= kendo.format("{0:n3}", value) #
```

Now, if you want what I needed, which was a dynamic amount of decimal places, then th only way of doing it is with a js function:

```
template: "#= formatAmount(value) #

function formatAmount(amount) {
    return kendo.toString(amount, "#,###.######");
}
```